# TypeError: 'cython_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable when parsing pydantic model

Tags: python, pydantic

I have a pydantic model (using pydantic 1.10.7):

```py
import re
from typing import Literal, Sequence
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field

ColumnTypeLiteral = Literal[
    "BOOLEAN",
    "DATE",
    "FLOAT",
    "INTEGER",
    "NUMERIC",
    "STRING",
]

class Column(BaseModel, frozen=True):
    name: str
    type: ColumnTypeLiteral
    mode: str = "NULLABLE"
    fields: Sequence = []

    def __hash__(self):
        return self.name.__hash__()

    @property
    def base_name(self) -> str:
        m = re.match(".+?(?=__|$)", self.name)
        if m:
            return m.group()
        else:
            return self.name

    @property
    def is_monthly_column(self) -> bool:
        pattern = re.compile(".*_{2}\\d{4}_\\d{1,2}")
        return True if pattern.match(self.name) else False

    @property
    def year_and_month(self) -> YearAndMonth | None:
        m = re.match(".*_{2}(\\d{4})_(\\d{1,2})", self.name)
        if m:
            return YearAndMonth(year=int(m.groups()[0]), month=int(m.groups()[1]))
        else:
            return None

    @classmethod
    def monthly_value_to_column_name(cls, base_name: str, year: int, month: int):
        return f"{base_name}__{year}_{month}"
```

This works as expected, and serializes to dictionaries as I'd expect:

```py
 columns = [
       {
            "name": "arrived_in_period",
            "type": "INTEGER",
            "mode": "NULLABLE",
            "fields": [],
        },
        {
            "name": "business_exclusion",
            "type": "BOOLEAN",
            "mode": "NULLABLE",
            "fields": [],
        },
]
```

But when I try to parse the above dictionaries when I use

```py
from pydantic import parse_obj_as

parsed_columns = parse_obj_as[List[Column], columns]
```

I get the following exception:

> TypeError: 'cython_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable

I see a lot of similar questions here on stackoverflow but none about `cython_function_or_method` specifically. I assume it has something to do with the regex properties but I am not sure.

Comment: Please post the full error output. It should show what file and function the error came from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is actually very simple (and a little embarrassing that I didn't catch it before posting here):
I was calling `parse_obj_as` with brackets instead of parentheses:

```py
parsed_columns = parse_obj_as[List[Column], my_dictionary]
```

and not what I should have been:

```py
parsed_columns = parse_obj_as(List[Column], my_dictionary)
```